# Java web service returning soap or json

Tags: java, json, web-services, soap, jax-rs

I need to create web service in Java with method which will be returning some object in SOAP or JSON format. The format depends on how the method is invoked.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/webservice/soap
http://localhost:8080/webservice/json
```

It must be the same method but with different format of returning object.

I know, that this effect is possible in .NET using WCF, but is it possible to do in Java? If it is, how to do that?

Comment: Just to be clear, SOAP is not a format, its a specification. Perhaps you are thinking XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to offer SOAP/XML + REST/JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089439/whats-the-best-way-to-offer-soap-xml-rest-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to the previous question I found / linked, I'd say that your best bet would be to create a set of MyService classes that contain the "meat" of your service code, and separate SOAP/XML and REST/JSON glue that calls your MyService APIs.