# Multiple Binding Configuration SOAP and JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap

I try implement soap and json methods same wcf contract class. My problem is when i remove namespace prefix (XXXX) at service name the soap methods are working correctly but json methods aren't. if i kept the namespace this time json methods are working correctly but soap methods thrown errors.

My configuration like this; any idea?

thanks for all.

```xml
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment> 
            <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                        <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="true" />
                        <serviceDebug  includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />
                    </behavior>        
                </serviceBehaviors>

          <endpointBehaviors >
                    <behavior name="JsonEndPointBehavior">
                        <webHttp />
                    </behavior>
            <behavior name="SoapEndPointBehavior">          
            </behavior>
                </endpointBehaviors>

            </behaviors>
            <services>
                <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="XXXX.ServerSide">

            <endpoint address=""                   
                      binding="webHttpBinding" 
                      contract="XXXX.service.IServerSide" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="JsonEndPointBehavior" />

            <endpoint address="soap"                    
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      contract="XXXX.IServerSide" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="SoapEndPointBehavior"/>
          </service>
```

Comment: I notice the namespace for your json contract is not the same as your soap contract. Are you using different contracts for each service? This is not necessary. If you're doing something tricky in your service implementation, it would be best to post your contract an implementation code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to offer SOAP/XML + REST/JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089439/whats-the-best-way-to-offer-soap-xml-rest-json)